# separate json data from html to json file

Tags: angularjs, json, amcharts

I need to separate chart Data in file HTML to file JSON and poster the chart and the table result --

[image]

thanks

Comment: i need to separate chartData to file json and keep all work 
link for tutorial :
[Automatically create a table of chart data on load](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/automatically-create-a-table-of-chart-data-on-load/)

Comment: Not clear at all what you are asking. Take some time to read [ask] then provide a proper explanation and relevant code

Comment: i m sorry for my bad english 
i need to leave the json from the html and make him in the external json file
link to code : [link] (https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/automatically-create-a-table-of-chart-data-on-load/)
thx

Answer (score 1):

When angular is running in the browser, the json file will be located in the server. You will need to do a angular $http.get to get the data into your angular controller. set the received data in your controller and feed it to your chart.

Comment: please if you can divise the code in the link in page html and page json and send to me :/

Comment: $http.get('data/the-file.json').success(function (data) {
  $scope.data= data;
 }).error(function(){
  //do something on error
 });

Comment: thnx for respond  think you not understand me good
https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/automatically-create-a-table-of-chart-data-on-load/
in thnis link in js part the json code i want to make him in external json file

Comment: sorry I dont know anything about amcharts. But check out this part of it: https://www.amcharts.com/kbc/external-data/