# create chart type serial and data table with external json file using amshart

Tags: angularjs, json, amcharts

How to create chart type **serial** and data **table** in the same page using **external file json** with **amcharts**

As it is shown in the link below

***link :*** https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/automatically-create-a-table-of-chart-data-on-load/

**How to separate json data from html to external json file ?**

[i need something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wszW.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a fiddle? In an angular context, the code provided in an answer to [the same question you asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42175618/6106614) is pretty close to what you need. Once the data is retrieved, call makeChart with the dataProvider property equal to the JSON data retrieved from your $http.get or however you accessed it. If you can provide a working fiddle of what you have now, you'll get a more targeted response.

Comment: How to create chart type serial and data table in the same page using external file json with amcharts

Comment: Did you not read my reply? Provide code for what you have done so far in your environment as a fiddle so we can help you. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for what folks on StackOverflow expect. The amcharts demo does not count.

Comment: Aaa oke thx :-D